# How to connect an android app with a localhost powered by xampp?

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, ubuntu, localhost

Please anyone who can assist!!

For a college project, I need to be able to access a localhost on Port 4212 from an android application. The app will need to take a photo and then send the photo back to a application running on Ubuntu for Windows to be parsed. The application running on Ubuntu is using port 4212. Using xampp I am able to access the general localhost (port 80) folder but unable to access the ubuntu based application (127.0.0.1:4212).

Any help, I will be so grateful and if there is any more information needed that you feel I haven't said, ask and I shall tell.

Comment: same as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device

Comment: try this:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47125117/6925888

Comment: Neither of these allow me to access port:4212, its being used by _Pastec_ application.... I need it to be able to access _Pastec_ to query it with a **curl** command